# How can I create a associated token address in solana from connected wallet address?

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-program-library

I want to create an associated token address in Solana from a connected wallet address. This is my code currently:

```
import { useWallet, useConnection } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

 ... 

  const wallet = useWallet();

  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = wallet;

const associatedAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
            mintPubkey,
            wallet.publicKey
          );
          const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
              wallet.publicKey,
              associatedAccount,
              wallet.publicKey,
              mintPubkey,
              TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
              ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            )
          );
       signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
          skipPreflight: true,     
        });

        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "confirmed");

...
```

But the tx is keep failing like this:
`https://solscan.io/tx/ZaQtfVkNkkAweGug2JfDYz8hcFXh4jDUEJoz2Lik6jPv8huFgzpMXMwui51VJsk8yHmpcWUD6UgnqdmRhu4Covh?cluster=devnet`
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use Token-2022, you need to specify it when generating the `associatedAccount` address. Otherwise it uses the default Token Program.

[Documentation: getAssociatedTokenAddress()](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getAssociatedTokenAddress)

```
const associatedAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
   mintPubkey,
   wallet.publicKey,
   false,
   TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
);
```